# PrimeFaces lazy scroll datatable has repeated items after ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable with lazy load and livescroll that works fine at first glance.

In the beginning the datatable loads items 0-20, when I scroll down items 20-40 are loaded and added to the datatable so that 0-40 are shown.

**Problem**: When I update the complete datatable (or form) via ajax the datatable is still 40 rows large but the items from 0-20 are repeated in rows 21-40.

The parameters of the LazyDataModel load() method are strange:
first: 0
pageSize: 20

**items.xhtml**

```
<p:dataTable var="_item" value="#{controller.lazyModel}"
    selectionMode="single" selection="#{controller.selection}" rowKey="#{_item.id}"
    scrollable="true" scrollRows="20" scrollHeight="125"
    liveScroll="true" lazy="true" >

<p:commandButton value="Update" update="@form"
    action="#{controller.updateSomething}" />
```

**ItemController.java**

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "controller")
public class ItemController
{
    private LazyDataModel<Item> itemLazyModel;
    private Item selectedItem;

    @EJB(lookup = "ejbpath...")
    protected DBService dbService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        itemLazyModel = new ItemLazyModel(dbService);
    }

    public void updateSomething()
    {
        // do something unrelated to the item list
    }

    // Getter and Setter for itemLazyModel and selectedItem
}
```

**ItemLazyModel.java**

```
public class ItemLazyModel extends LazyDataModel<Item> {

private DBService dbService;
private Map<String, Item> data;

public ItemLazyModel(DBService service)
{
    this.dbService = dbService;
    data = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    setRowCount(dbService.getItemsSize());
}

@Override
public Item getRowData(String rowKey)
{
    return data.get(rowKey);
}

@Override
public Object getRowKey(Item object)
{
    return object.getId();
}

@Override
public List<Item> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters)
{
    List<Item> result = dbService.getItems(first, pageSize);
    for (Item item : result)
    {
        data.put(item.getId(), item);
    }

    return result;
}}
```

When changing to a paginated lazy datatable everything is fine. The datatable is on the correct 2nd page after the update and shows items 21-40.

If I set the pageSize manually and use getPageSize() in the load method, I am able to return the correct items from 0-40. But the rendered datatable still has the same problem with repeating items 1-20.

Is there maybe an incompatiblity  between lazy, liveScroll and ajax updates where the datatable forgets its current scroll position (like the page when paginated)?

JSF: 2.2.13 (Mojarra)

Primefaces: 6.1

Comment: Works great here... Please read [ask] and [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info. Most likely you add everything **again** to an existing list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and hints. I updated the question.

Comment: Related? https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1321

Comment: load() method is called in my case. But this might be related because if have incorrect items (duplicates) in the list as well: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/405